# React Native v5: Cannot receive updated route.params from another screen component using navigation.navigate()

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to update route.params everytime a screen submits a form that sends data to another screen that shows this submitted data. But it just navigates and route.params remains undefined. Here is my navigation architecture.

Drawer => Tab => Stack (for each tab)

App.js

```
return (
      <>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator
            drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
          >
            <Drawer.Screen
              name="Main"
              component={BottomTabScreen}
              options={{
                title: "Overview",
                headerLeft: () => <Icon.Button name="md-menu" size={25} />,
              }}
            />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </>
    );
```

This is the where most of navigation is in MainTabScreen.js. It contains the Tab Navigation Component that is called in App.js. Each Tab Screen is a Stack: Home, Favorites, Profile, Settings.

MainTabScreen.js

```
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    tabBarOptions={{
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63",
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeStackScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: "Home",
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Favorites"
      component={FavoritesStackScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: "Favorites",
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
        tabBarBadge: 3,
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Profile"
      component={ProfileStackScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: "Profile",
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Settings"
      component={SettingsStackScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: "Settings",
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cogs" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default BottomTabScreen;

// //HOME
const HomeStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
    headerMode="screen"
    screenOptions={{
      headerTintColor: "white",
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "tomato" },
      headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "BalsamiqSans_700Bold", fontSize: 30 },
    }}
  >
    <HomeStack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        title: "Home",
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon.Button
            name="md-menu"
            backgroundColor="tomato"
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            size={25}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <HomeStack.Screen
      name="Explore"
      component={ExploreScreen}
      options={{
        title: "Explore",
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon.Button
            name="arrow-back-outline"
            backgroundColor="tomato"
            onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
            size={25}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
);

//Favorites
const FavoritesStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <FavoritesStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="FavoritesScreen"
    headerMode="screen"
    screenOptions={{
      headerTintColor: "white",
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "tomato" },
      headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "BalsamiqSans_700Bold", fontSize: 30 },
    }}
  >
    <FavoritesStack.Screen
      name="Favorites"
      component={FavoritesScreen}
      options={{
        title: "Favorites",
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon.Button
            name="md-menu"
            backgroundColor="tomato"
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            size={25}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </FavoritesStack.Navigator>
);

//Profile
const ProfileStackScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => (
  <ProfileStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="ProfileScreen"
    headerMode="screen"
    screenOptions={{
      headerTintColor: "white",
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "tomato" },
      headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "BalsamiqSans_700Bold", fontSize: 30 },
    }}
  >
    <ProfileStack.Screen
      name="Profile"
      component={ProfileScreen}
      options={{
        title: "Profile",
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon.Button
            name="md-menu"
            backgroundColor="tomato"
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            size={25}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </ProfileStack.Navigator>
);

//SETTINGS
const SettingsStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <SettingsStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
    headerMode="screen"
    screenOptions={{
      headerTintColor: "white",
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "tomato" },
      headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "BalsamiqSans_700Bold", fontSize: 30 },
    }}
  >
    <SettingsStack.Screen
      name="Settings"
      component={Settings}
      options={{
        title: "Settings",
      }}
    />
  </SettingsStack.Navigator>
);
```

I am trying to get HomeScreen to send data via navigation.navigate to ProfileScreen. I used a modal to create this form

HomeScreen.js

```
      <Modal visible={modalOpen} animationType="slide">
        <View style={StyleSheet.modalContent}>
          <MaterialIcons
            name="close"
            size={24}
            onPress={() => setModal(false)}
          />
          <ImageBackground
            style={styles.modalTop}
            source={require("../img/modalTop.jpg")}
          >
            <Text style={styles.modalTopText}>Create.</Text>
            <Text style={styles.modalTopText}>Share.</Text>
          </ImageBackground>
          
        {/*Button to submit and send data to ProfileScreen*/}
          <MaterialIcons
            name="add"
            size={24}
            onPress={() => {
              setI((prev) => prev + 1);
              navigation.navigate("Profile", recipe);
            }}
          />
          {/*Name of recipe input */}

          <TextInput
            value={recipe.name}
            onChangeText={(e) => handleChange(e, "name")}
            placeholder="Put name of Meal"
          />

          {/*Time of recipe input */}
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={(e) => handleChange(e, "time")}
            placeholder="Give estimate how long"
          />

          {/*Steps of recipe input */}
          <TextInput
            value={recipe.steps}
            onChangeText={(e) => handleChange(e, "steps")}
            placeholder="The steps"
          />

          {/*Image of recipe input */}
          <TextInput
            value={recipe.image}
            onChangeText={(e) => handleChange(e, "steps")}
            placeholder="url of image"
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
```

I am using a Flatlist in ProfileScreen.js to list the data from HomeScreen.js.
I am also using useEffect() to listen submission of this data.

ProfileScreen.js

```
  const [followers, setFollower] = useState(0);
  const [following, setFollowing] = useState(0);
  // Our list that receives the data
  const [recipeList, setRecipeList] = useState([]);
  const [params, setParams] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params !== undefined) {
      setRecipeList((prev) => [...prev, route.params]);
    }
  }, [route.params]);

  //render each MyRecipe
  const _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.recipeContent}>
        <Text style={styles.recipeContentName}>{item.name}</Text>
        <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
          <Avatar.Image style={styles.recipeImage} size={80}></Avatar.Image>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.recipeContentTime}>{item.time} mins</Text>
        {(() => {
          let a = item.steps;
          let res = [];
          a.forEach((step) => {
            res.push(<Text style={styles.recipeContentStep}>{step}</Text>);
          });
          return res;
        })()}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

ProfileScreen.js FlatList

```
<View style={styles.myRecipesBody}>
          <FlatList
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
            data={recipeList}
            renderItem={_renderItem}
          />
        </View>
```

I'm wondering if this issue is because of the nature of my navigation architecture, or am I listening to route.params incorrectly? Thanks!

GitHub repo: https://github.com/rrzhang139/myRNapp.git

Comment: You are mixing react-navigation v4 and v5 in the same project. Please use only of them.

Comment: Can you specify where I am using v4?

Comment: withNavigation is exported from react-navigation v4. Its now extracted from the package and available as compatibility layer. You can read more about here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/compatibility/ or here https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6821

Comment: You mean NavigationActions? How is this affecting my ability to send data from screen to screen?

Comment: No, in your git repo you are wrapping HomeScreen using withNavigator which is from v4 package. I explained this in my last comment